# SVG linear-gradient fill works on desktop view but not on mobile. How can I fix this?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, gradient, fill

So I have a logo for a website I'm making with React and Express. The SVG path is returned from a function which is called in both Desktop and Mobile components. Here's my default.css (which stands for default style, applied to both mobile and desktop, I'm only changing color stuff here.

```
svg {
    fill: url(#logo-gradient);
}
#logo-gradient {
    --color-stop-1: rgba(242, 68, 132, 1);
    --color-stop-2: rgba(237, 136, 173, 1);
    --color-stop-3: #fbbed4;
```

}

Here's how it works well on Desktop view: [image: Desktop]

Not working on Mobile:

[image: Mobile1]

However, if I use `fill: red;` it shows on mobile as expected, of course, in red:
[image: MobileRed]

I have no idea what could be wrong, It should just work. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Responding to "somethinghere", I thought it would be irrelevant to include svg code since it's returned by a function and the same function is called on both mobile and desktop components... But here it is:

```
getLogo = () => {
    return   (
        <svg
        viewBox="0 0 250 50"
        width="250"
        height="50"
        version="1.1"
        id="svg3785">
            <defs>
                <linearGradient id="logo-gradient">
                    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="var(--color-stop-1)" />
                    <stop offset="77%" stop-color="var(--color-stop-2)" />
                    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="var(--color-stop-3)" />
                </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <path d="M 17.699219 8.7597656  ... really long path"/>
        </svg>
    )
}
```

And in component (including only parent divs):

```
<div className="logo-container">
    {this.getLogo()}
</div>
```

And for the Mobile:

```
<div className="nav-resp-logo-container">
    {this.getLogo()}
</div>
```

Comment: You should include the relevant SVG code as well.

Comment: Edited my post to include svg code.

Comment: Depending on your browser chosen, svg code might not be compatible with all browsers. Or contain a mistake. With this code included, your css can be tested by others in exactly the same environment.

Comment: But it's interesting how it works on one SVG but not on the other... And what's also interesting is how fill: red works but not the gradient which works on the exact same svg in a different component...

Comment: Oh waw you are using css variables _inside_ the svg. Not sure if this all works as you'd expect in the first place - I can't even get animations to update appropriately with variables... Otherwise it looks like it should function. For this, though, maybe you can look into `-webkit-bacground-fill: text`? Would highly simplify your setup here...

Comment: I looked up, and could not find anything about background-fill or -webkit-background-fill... The svg appears in the DOM, but it just doesn't show up on mobile view. It's there, and it loads the css properly as I can see it in the devTools, and as soon as I remove the tick from the fill option, the svg appears in it's original color. Strange. Very strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222738/discussion-between-redmaster-and-somethinghere).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to simplify your code to something testable, and it all seems to be working fine across devices on my end:

```css
:root {
  --g1: red;
  --g2: green;
  --g3: blue;
}

#definitions {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-100%,-100%);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#logo text {
  fill: url(#logo-gradient);
}
```

```html
<svg
    viewBox="0 0 250 50"
    width="250"
    height="50"
    id="definitions"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="logo-gradient">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="var(--g1)" />
            <stop offset="77%" stop-color="var(--g2)" />
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="var(--g3)" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
<svg
    id="logo"
    viewBox="0 0 250 50"
    width="250"
    height="50"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text x="0" y="40" style="font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold;">Hello World</text>
</svg>
```

Which means your problem might not be in the code you are showing us. Maybe the logo is accidentally hidden on mobile? What browsers are you testing this on? Which devices?

The only advice I could give your is to *ensure* that you have a defined `XMLNS`, or XML namespace. If you do not, funky things can happen on certain browsers - mostly older ones. So make sure your `<svg>` tags at least contain this:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```